# Что такое "писать грамотно"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Мне кажется, что людей, которые вообще не делают ошибок в русском языке, не так много. Может быть, только специалисты-филологи, да и то не все. Тогда что же, все остальные — безграмотные?
Какого человека вообще можно считать грамотным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Об идеальной грамотности никто и не говорит. Давайте обратимся к Большому Энциклопедическому словарю: ГРАМОТНОСТЬ - определенная степень владения навыками чтения, письма в соответствии с грамматическими нормами родного языка. Применительно к характеристике населения - один из базовых показателей его социально-культурного развития. Конкретное содержание понятия грамотности исторически изменчиво, имеет тенденцию к расширению с ростом общественных требований к развитию индивида: от элементарных умений читать, писать, считать - к владению некоторым комплексом различных общественно необходимых знаний и навыков, позволяющих человеку сознательно участвовать в социальных процессах (т. н. функциональная грамотность).

Вот мы и говорим о функциональной грамотности - овладении орфоэпическими, морфологическими, синтаксическими, орфографическими нормами в такой степени, чтобы тебя понимали и над тобой не смеялись, как сегодня я в маршрутке, прочитав объявление: Уважаемые пассажиры, имеющие льготные проездные! Проездной действителен только при наличии документа удостоверяющего личность (оригинал), заверенную печатью или  копию организации или органа ей принадлежащего. Интересно, кто сколько и каких ошибок здесь найдёт, но я не поняла, кто кого или что должен заверять и чем.

Comment: Мне особенно про "копию организации или органа" понравилось)))))))))))))

Comment: Я даже представила чей-то орган, заверяющий чью-то личность, и засмеялась, окружающие не поняли,  а когда я передала свои ощущения приятельнице, она так хохотала, что на нас плохо посмотрели. Надо было вслух сказать ...

Comment: "Оригинал личности, заверенной печатью" - тоже неплохо.

Comment: Я сегодня снова ехала в той маршрутке, оказалось, я чуть приукрасила, не запомнила сразу. Там ещё и ".. или органа выдавшей его ", а не "принадлежащего ей". Я выпала в осадок. Интересно, это долго будет висеть, никто не читает или всем всё равно?

Answer (score 2):

Грамотным можно назвать того, чья безграмотность не бросается в глаза окружающим.

Comment: В стране слепых и кривой - король.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо, хоть не указали конкретный орган, маршрутчики это могут.

> Какого человека вообще можно считать грамотным?

Того человека, кто учится на чужих ошибках и не стесняется признавать свои и исправлять их; а также пользуется справочной литературой.

Answer (score 0):

Я не филолог, но вот грамотность - 100%. Что я делаю не так?

Писать грамотно - соблюдать **все** кодифицированные нормы языка (орфография, пунктуация, грамматика и еще какие-то умные слова в списке есть... забыл). Все, более *никаких фантазий*.

Кто не соблюдает - безграмотен, вопрос только в **степени безграмотности**, а не в классификации явления.

Comment: Нормы не всегда чёткие. Посмотрите хотя бы споры на этом форуме о пунктуации или о выделении основы предложения.

Comment: @stopkran - так и споры от безграмотности! Хайль Розенталь!

Comment: grammar-nazi?.. grammar-trolling?..

Comment: А разные споры лингвистов - от безграмотности? Вы уверены в правильности своих действий только потому, что не знаете, где сомневаться.

Comment: Барсук, всех правил соблюсти невозможно. Ибо правописание (пунктуация в особенности) - не математически строгая система. Есть лакуны, есть спорные случаи, есть противоречия (последних, по счастью, очень немного).

Comment: @Лорана - лигнвисты сопрят о лингвистике, о науке, а не об азбучных истинах. В спор профессионалов я, квалифицированный чайник, не полезу - я чайник в лингвистике, но не самоуверенный ламер по жизни
@behemothus - а я и не знаю правил и не применяю их (хотя "вспомнить" - могу напрячься), я просто **помню**, как правильно. Пока правила не сменяется - я грамотен (в плане орфографии и пунктуации, грамматика - на уровне "чувства языка", ее, конечно же, формально не помню, но многочтение хороших изданий помогает - мастерство не пропить)

Comment: >Пока правила не сменяется - я грамотен   
  
"Велик могучим русский языка!"
ЗЫ Это к вопросу о грамматике и "чуйстве языка". 
Опечатки вешь понятное, я сам их леплю без всякой меры, но заявлять, что я грамотнее даже тех, с кем я спорю не на живот, а насмерть... Перебор будет.

Comment: это:

> но не самоуверенный ламер по жизни

плохо гармонирует с:

> но вот грамотность - 100%

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще в подобных схоластических спорах стараюсь не участвовать, но тут возникла причина...

> Какого человека вообще можно считать грамотным?

Никакого. Или, наоборот, всех, кто умеет читать и писать.
Понятие размыто. Зависит от контекста, от ситуации, от авторского смысла...

ЗЫ.
Вот тут вспомнилось. Грамотным можно считать человека, который без ошибок напишет следующий диктант (к сожалению, вариант не совсем канонический, поэтому могут быть накладки)

*С камушка на камушек прыгал воробышек, а на дощатой террасе, задрапированной гобеленами с видами кронштадтского инфантерийского полка в дефензиве, веснушчатая свояченица протоиерея и вдова подьячего Агриппина Саввична под аккомпанемент шепелявящего граммофона потчевала восседающего на скрипящей кожаной оттоманке коллежского асессора, околоточного надзирателя и индифферентного деда Фаддея Аполлинарьевича винегретом со снетками.*